# Why can polar molecules like water pass aquaporin better than unpolar like H2 or CO2

Tags: biochemistry, structural-biology

We learned in our lecutre, that aquaporin lets Water pass, but blocks Ions like H+ and unpolar molecules like CO2 and H2. The reasons for the Ion blocking are comprehensible, but I dont get, why less-than-water-polar molecules are blocked. Our professor said, it has something to do with the water molecules are orient in the aquaporin towards the positively charged n-terminus of the alpha helix, but why is that an advantage compared to non polar not charged molecules?

Comment: Electrostatics.